# in-addr.arpa. responses not triggering callbacks in ServiceListener

Tags: jmdns

I am trying to setup some ServiceListeners, in particular two:

```
zeroConf.addServiceListener("100.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.", myListener);
zeroConf.addServiceListener("_workstation._tcp.local.", myListener);
```

Whenever I do this, I get callbacks for myListener on serviceResolved() and serviceAdded() for all services that match "_workstation._tcp.local."  However, I get no callbacks for "100.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa." ... despite the fact that jmDns sends out the queries, and a response comes back!  I've attached a tcpdump of the request packets that jmdns sends out, and the response that comes back for it.  However, the callbacks are not called so I never see the response in my application.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~gnychis/jmdns_nocallback.pcap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging of the actual event type that comes in, the event type resolves to "_tcp.in-addr.arpa."  Adding this to my service listeners triggers the call back.